# Using rails to retrieve tables from the model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called Student. Lets assume that it has two fields Grade(string) and Name(string). Grades can take the values `A,B,C,D,E,F`.I have a form inside my View which provides a check box for selecting the grades .Since it is a check box I can have multiple selection. Based on this selection it will show the Names and their respective grades.

The User selected grades are stored in an array called `@grades` in the controller. I need to compare and select it from the model and i wrote the following code which I presume is not correct since it reports error

`@students = Student.where("grade = ?",@grades)` 
How to I actually retrieve this?

Comment: Could be solved easily by googling or reading the guides.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I had read through [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html) .Couldnt find what i wanted.What i found in this guide is what i tried which is [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions)

Comment: That would work if, like in the example, you're testing equality to one thing. In your example you'd need to use `Student.where("grade IN (?)", @grades)`, as that is correct SQL. However this is inferior to @marek's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Student.where(grade: @grades)
```